# SharePoint Search query

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I have a word (docx) document stored on the OneDrive for business. It has a structure like :

```
<title>  
Book Title
</title>  
<author>  
High  
</author>
```

And then I use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client for searching title and author

```
   var targetSite = new Uri("https://my-site.sharepoint.com");
    var login = "login";
    var password = "pass";
    var securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password)
    {
        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
    }
var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(targetSite))
{
    clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;

    var query = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
    query.QueryText = "<title></title><author></author>";
    var searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
    var result = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(query);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

}
```

But it does not work. it returns only word title and author. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to find data between tags <title>.

Comment: It would be better if that's specified in the question, because it isn't so understandable, and quite a strange requirement too..

Answer (score 0):

Syntax should follow the *Keyword Query Language* specification (you're using `KeywordQuery`)

[Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx)

For what you ask you should use something like

```
query.QueryText = "Author:John AND Title:Test*";
```